# Excel pivot table breaking up for whole number items

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office, pivot-table

I couldn't think of a better title. Please bear with me!

I have the data as the following image shows:

[image: data]

I create a pivot table using the range `'Sheet1'!$A$1:$E$33`. The table displayed is as follows:

[image: pivot table]

Why is the data skewed for only the set of *Round 3* and no other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause of this behaviour. The cells in column A are of data type *Number*, with 0 decimals. I used autofill feature after selecting the first 8 cells, namely, the values `1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2`. This caused the later values to be decimals like: `2.54, 2.78, 2.93` etc. These were getting rounded to **3** but since they weren't actually 3; pivot table was displaying them in separate rows.